# Mass Memory Default directory

Tags: c#

in my application i want to support both mass memory and memory card. but is the defualt drive name for mass memory "F:" ?

or it might change . and how could i know if it changes ?!?

Note : Lang is C# , windows application , Mobile series :S60

thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean Mass Storage Device?  There is no default drive letter, and the user can always change them.  It's best not to rely on the drive letter that the device will be assigned, and instead pop up a list of possible devices (see Google's picasa as an exmample)

Comment: Eng mentions this is for a windows mobile device, so probably not mass storage device. Drive letter allocation is differrent on windows mobile, but your suggestion is what I would recommend never the less.

Comment: In fact this is *not* a windows mobile device.  Instead he's insisted on opening something like 5 questions for the same problem, all of which are terribly ambiguous.  It seems it's a Nokia phone (we're supposed to read minds).